# How to repeat json object inside of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

How can I repeat the value of names in the following json object inside ng-options.

```
$scope.networkIds =[
    {
        "name": "ghdth",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "dddd",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Nrgyr",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Ntehyt
        "value": []
    }
]
```

Currently I am using this code

```
<select id="networkID"  ng-model="usageStatistics.networkID" ng-options="networkID as networkID for networkID in networkIds" ng-change=""  class="form-control" ng-required="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
$scope.networkIds =[
    {
        "name": "ghdth",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "dddd",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Nrgyr",
        "value": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Ntehyt",
        "value": []
    }
];
<select id="networkID"  ng-model="usageStatistics.networkID" ng-options="network as network.name for network in networkIds"  class="form-control" ng-required="true">
```

Comment: I had tried this. Is is populating the values inside ng-otions as "undefined"

Comment: @user3177493 pls try now, copy and paste the above code

Comment: How can i access the same names in javascript?
    for(var i=0;i<=$scope.networkIds.length;i++){       
      $log.info(angular.toJson(networkIDsArray[i].name));     
            }
I am getting error as ---> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="networkID"  ng-model="usageStatistics.networkID" class="form-control" ng-required="true">

    <option ng-repeat"nId in networkIds" value="{{nId.value}}">{{nId.name}}</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to improve this answer's quality.